# ProgressBar isn't updating

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a progressbar that that is show progress returned by the backgroundworker do_dowork event like below .

```
       if (ftpSourceFilePath.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
            {
                FtpWebRequest objRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpSourceFilePath);
                NetworkCredential objCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                objRequest.Credentials = objCredential;
                objRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                FtpWebResponse objResponse = (FtpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
                StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
                int len = 0;
                int iProgressPercentage = 0;
                FileStream objFS = new FileStream((cd+"\\VolareUpdate.rar"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);

                    while ((len = objReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {

                            objFS.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                            iRunningByteTotal += len;
                            double dIndex = (double)(iRunningByteTotal);
                            double dTotal = (double)buffer.Length;
                            double dProgressPercentage =  (dIndex / dTotal);

                            iProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage);

                            if (iProgressPercentage > 100)
                            {
                                iProgressPercentage = 100;

                            }

                            bw.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);


                        }
}
```

However, my progressbar does not update. While searching , i was told the UI thread is being blocked and then i thought may be passing the progress outside the loop will do the trick. then i change to this

```
if (ftpSourceFilePath.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
                {
                    FtpWebRequest objRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpSourceFilePath);
                    NetworkCredential objCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                    objRequest.Credentials = objCredential;
                    objRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                    FtpWebResponse objResponse = (FtpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
                    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
                    int len = 0;
                    int iProgressPercentage = 0;
                    FileStream objFS = new FileStream((cd+"\\VolareUpdate.rar"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
    while ((len = objReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {

                            objFS.Write(buffer, 0, len);
                            iRunningByteTotal += len;
                            double dIndex = (double)(iRunningByteTotal);
                            double dTotal = (double)buffer.Length;
                            double dProgressPercentage =  (dIndex / dTotal);

                            iProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage);

                            if (iProgressPercentage > 100)
                            {
                                iProgressPercentage = 100;

                            }
                           // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                              iProgressPercentage++;
                         //    SetText("F", true);




                        }

                         bw.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);
                         progressBar.Refresh();

}
```

However still didn't help. When i put break point in my workerprogresschanged event, it show the progressbar.value however does not update. I tried progressbar.update(0, i also tried sleeping the thread for a while in the loop still didn't help. Please any suggestion/help would be appreciated .

Comment: Are you sure your initial call to `objReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)` is actually returning a value other than 0? If `buffer` is initially an empty array I can see how this might result in unexpected behavior. A little debugging may be necessary to prove what'd going on.

Comment: is your percentage when calculated a decimal like 0.3?  Is so, need to multiply by 100.  Casting 0.3 to int is going to make progress 0.  Also are you handling the progress event from backgroundworker to update the bar.

Comment: Yah its . OK see my update above. You can from there. It read and returns the file . My problem is with the `    bw.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);`

Comment: No sir. My percentage is actually a number. Given the fact that my the file i am downloading is of 20mb , the dindex is at one point greater than total. Thats why i put the if below to make it a whole 100 where greater than 100. Also like i mentioned. i cut the progresbar.value and it was indeed progresssive numbers up t o 100. however it does not update the progress.

Comment: is your progressbar not updating atall or updating for sometime and stopping inbetween?

Comment: @Sudhakar it's not updating at all despite the fact that it receive the respective values returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your reply . I achieved this using a delegate method like below .

```
  delegate void SetProgressBar(int percentage, bool logic);
        private void SetProgress(int percentage, bool logic)
        {
            if (progressBar.InvokeRequired)  
            {
                SetProgressBar d = new SetProgressBar(SetProgress);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { percentage, logic });

            }
            else
            {

                progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
                progressBar.Value = percentage;
                progressBar.Text = percentage.ToString() + "%";

            }


        }
```

And my dowork event

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;


  while ((len = objReader.BaseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                           .....

                          .......
                            int iProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage * 100);
                            bw.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);

                        }
}
```

In my Progress changed event, triggers the delegate method above .

```
   private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {


             SetProgress(e.ProgressPercentage, true);


        }
```

This works great without an issue...Thanks for all ur contribution.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, you can't access UI Thread from dowork() method. You need to use progresschanged event.

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo and [C#, Updating a Progress Bar Using Background Worker From a Different Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974213/c-updating-a-progress-bar-using-background-worker-from-a-different-class)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

Comment: I use that to receive the progress and the value shows correct. However the progress bar does not show the value. It does not update at all.

Comment: @NuruSalihu : so it confirmed that your UI is not ressponding/getting reflected for the changes. is your window freezing while downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing a call to Application.DoEvents()

In long running tasks like a loop if you want to make any UI changes then you should call

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

this will reflect changes made to UI.